# How to make the banner image visible through the transparent navigation bar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I've written the following code with Bootstrap 4. On the picture below I describe what I want to achieve. Thank you! [image]

```
    <style>
        div.jumbotron {
            background: #458392 url("img/banner.jpg") no-repeat right;
        }

        nav.navbar {
            background: rgba(69, 131, 146, 0.4);
        }
    </style>

<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-inverse">
  /*some code*/
</nav>

<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid text-white">
  /*some code*/
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: http://xomisse.com/blog/make-navigation-bar-other-blog-elements-partially-transparent/

Comment: I've already used the opacity property and rgba value. It didn't help. The color of the navbar became lighter and that's all. What I need is to make the banner image visible through the navbar.

Comment: did you try changing z-index?

Comment: can you share link to website?

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, your need to actually put your navbar over the banner. Currently they are just set next to each other. 
Try to adjust the position - absolute or fixed.

Comment: You're right. I'm new to bootstrap, so I don't really know how to code with it. Now I've put the navbar element over the banner and almost got what I wanted.